# How to resize barcode generated by barbecue api?

Tags: java, barcode, barcode-printing

I have generated the barcode using barbecue and now I want to resize the barcode as per my need. I tried with BufferedImage and then I got barcode with different size but then I get an additional black line under the barcode.

```
    public class GenerateBarcode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String initialString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the text here");
        Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(initialString);
        BufferedImage bi = BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barcode);
        }
    }
```

Here I want to resize "bi".

Answer (score 1):

To resize any BufferedImage, you can create a new one and draw your old one on top of it with a scaling applied. For example:

```
double scale = 2;
BufferedImage scaledBi = new BufferedImage((int)(bi.getWidth()*scale), (int) (bi.getHeight()*scale), bi.getType());
Graphics2D g2 = scaledBi.createGraphics();
g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, scaledBi.getWidth(), scaledBi.getHeight(), 0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), null);
```

`scaledBi` now contains your scaled image. Note that this is not vector based, so I am not sure of the quality. To increase scaling quality, you can play with the [rendering hints](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html).

Comment: Thanks.I also got another solution by direct changing the size of original image and then converting it into BufferedImage.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Barcode b = BarcodeFactory.create2of7(jTextField1.getText());
b.setBarHeight(5);
b.setBarWidth(1);
```